# combine multiple columns to a new column in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns

I want to combine multiple columns of binary values (`0/1`) into one where my data frame columns are named like this.

```
      A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2
row1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  
row2  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0
```

I want to combine all columns of the same number in a loop and create a new col for them so it it looks

```
     newCol1  newCol2
row1  "1011"   "0110"  
row2  "1011"   "1110"
```

€: Didn't been specify enough on the question, its actually important that every row is separate like I edited it.

Comment: Do you want columns `A1, A2, A3` ie of the same letter to become one column `A` or do you want columns `A1,B1,C1` of the same number to become one column `1`??

Comment: `unstack(transform(stack(dat),ind=sub("\\D+","",ind)))` id you are interested in the number and `unstack(transform(stack(dat),ind=sub("\\d+","",ind)))` if you are interested in the letters

Comment: Added some values to the input example matching the question's expected output. Got rid of what was not needed. Formating and English language improved.

Comment: Wanst precise enought edited my question. Thanks so far anyway